# What DataMapper plugin gives :null property option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datamapper

I'm trying to adapt a piece of code that has:

```
property :email, String, :index => true, :null => false, :length => 1000
```

in the model definition. I'm getting this error:

```
ArgumentError: options :null are unknown
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dm-core-0.10.2/lib/dm-core/property.rb:901:in `assert_valid_options'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dm-core-0.10.2/lib/dm-core/property.rb:811:in `initialize'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dm-core-0.10.2/lib/dm-core/model/property.rb:51:in `new'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dm-core-0.10.2/lib/dm-core/model/property.rb:51:in `property'
```

So I think that I'm missing a DataMapper plugin.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of any DataMapper plugin that uses the `:null` option.

On older versions of DataMapper you'd want to use `:nullable => false`.  The most recent DataMapper (0.10.2) provides the clearer syntax `:required => true`.  The other option is still supported, but is deprecated.